# Show that the Frobenius solution for the equation $x^2y'' + xy' + x^2y = 0$ is $y = \sum_0^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $$x^2y'' + xy' + x^2y = 0$$ is the differential equation

> $$y = \sum_0^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2n}}{2^{2n} (n!)^2}$$
> is the required solution of the differential equation

There is only one root of the indicial equation ie. $r = 0$

If we try to get the coefficients of $x^{n+r}$ by substituting the $y = \sum a_n x^{n+r}$ then we get $$a_n = -\frac{-a_{n-2}}{(n+r)^2}$$

From this the given statement can be proved pretty easily except two caveats:

1. We dont know the value of $a_0$ (unless of course the solution is particular in which case $a_0 = 1$ can be assumed).
2. and we need $a_1 = 0$, but I could not find a way of proving that. Where can we get it from?

Comment: Please fix the differential equation in the title and put it also into the main body of the question.

Comment: @Gary ok edited it

Comment: There is no such thing as *the* Frobenius solution. To obtain a particular solution, you need initial conditions on it, e.g., by specifying $y$ and $y'$ at a specific point. This will determine $a_0$ and $a_1$.

Comment: @Gary but still I think $a_1 = 0$ can be proven somehow, since the indicial equation has only one root so we can't have both $a_0$ and $a_1$ to be undetermined constants because that will give two series solutions